# Rollback AWS Beanstalk deploy via CLI

Tags: jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a jenkins job which will build and deploy grails to AWS Beanstalk, and a script which then checks the HTTP status of the deployed page. Is there a way to rollback the change if it does not return a 200?

Answer (score 0):

Grab what version is running before deployment and save it.

Deploy.

If it's not a 200OK just run a beanstalk deploy on the previous version you captured.

As far as "rollbacks" no, that's usually done in single transactions to make sure data consistency is held.